# Border-color in input tag will not work when the text is editing(CSS3)

Tags: html, css

I want to make a **blue-style CSS framework**. I was dealing with *input* tag now and I want to use *Border-color* in it. However, when I was editing the text, it will turn into black instead of this color.

Here is my code:

CSS:

```
input[class*=bright][type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
    color: rgb(150,230,255);
}
input[class*=bright][type=text]::-moz-placeholder {
    /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
    color: rgb(235,255,255);
    opacity: 1;
}
input[class*=bright][type=text] {
  color:rgb(50,200,255);
  background:rgb(235,255,255);
  border-style:solid;
  border-color:rgb(50,200,255);
  border-radius:5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input class="bright" type="text" placeholder="test">
```

The border will be black when I tested it on Edge and Chrome and they both show the black border.

I also tried this but it did not work neither:

```
input[class*=bright][type=text]:active{
  border-color:rgb(50,200,255);
}
```

I wonder if there is a solution to make it work when editing, or changing it into a different bonder color when editing the text.

I want a CSS3-only solution in that this is only a framework by CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if this suits your requirements:

```css
input[class*=bright][type=text]::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  /* WebKit, Blink, Edge */
  color: rgb(150, 230, 255);
}

input[class*=bright][type=text]::-moz-placeholder {
  /* Mozilla Firefox 19+ */
  color: rgb(235, 255, 255);
  opacity: 1;
}

input[class*=bright][type=text] {
  color: rgb(50, 200, 255);
  background: rgb(235, 255, 255);
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: rgb(50, 200, 255);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

input[class*=bright][type=text]:focus {
  outline: none !important;
  border-color: rgb(50, 200, 255);
}
```

```html
<input class="bright" type="text" placeholder="test">
```